# Is there any tools for Android Studio to notify user there is a newer version for the dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio

say there is a newer version of 3rd party dependency released. How does our Android Studio be notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gradle, they recommend to build against exact versions.

But you can write it like below to use latest library version

```
compile "junit:junit:4.+"
```

"*But the + is not recommended because it can break builds when libraries depend on each other and use different versions.*"

Check this. it may help you.

**Gradle plugin to discover dependency updates**

https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: But the `+` is not recommended because it can break builds when libraries depend on each other and use different versions.

Comment: Thanks i will add this to the answer for reference.